# INtel 3956ABG WPA wireless not working on Thinkpad T60

Tags: 11.10, wireless, upgrade, thinkpad, intel-wireless

I recently upgraded my Thinkpad T60 from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10. My wireless worked on 11.04 without a problem. Using 11.10, it detects all the wireless networks available, but will not connect to it. It does however connect to any non-encrypted network. My wireless network uses WPA2-Personal.

The problem is not my wireless network, as my other devices can connect to it properly.

How can I get my Thinkpad T60's wireless working again on 11.10?

The wireless interface is a PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection from Intel Corporation.

Threads I'm following on Ubuntu Forum:

- [Having trouble connecting to WPA after upgrade to 11.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1862484&page=5)
- [[64 bit] Can't connect to wireless after 11.10 upgrade](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1862484&page=5)

I posted a Wireless issue too:

- [Intel 3956ABG wireless not working with WPA](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11370215#post11370215)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was discussed and solved on on the Ubuntu Forum [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1865420).

The problem is with the network manager.

1. Install **wicd** using Synaptic or software center.
2. Remove network manager using: *sudo apt-get purge network-manager network-manager-gnome*

Then use wicd to connect to your wireless network using WPA2.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

not working this is not a solution its not working and i also try to downgrade to naty kernel and its also not working. maybe this is because of gnome3 integeration but no one did fix this i search all over the net no solution guys me going back to natty

Comment: Works for me ... but wicd has a very complicated interface - would be better to fix NM.