# Wireless connection keeps dropping with an Intel 3945ABG card

Tags: 11.10, wireless, connection, intel-wireless

After updating to 11.10 from 11.04, my wireless connection keeps dropping off from time to time.

Now, I already experience this problem when I was using 10.04 (the workaround back then was to replace NetworkManager with wicd. But the thing is I'm not really a fan of wicd and seeing that the problem seems to have been fixed in previous releases, I think there's a similar solution that I can try.

Here's the some more detail of my system

```
$ sudo lshw -C network

*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:19:d2:ad:20:4d
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:44 memory:84100000-84100fff

$ sudo lsmod | grep iwl

iwl3945                73329  0 
iwl_legacy             71499  1 iwl3945
mac80211              272785  2 iwl3945,iwl_legacy
cfg80211              172392  3 iwl3945,iwl_legacy,mac80211

$ dmesg

[43972.920056] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[44533.245630] wlan0: deauthenticating from 94:0c:6d:c0:51:ca by local choice (reason=3)
[44533.260462] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[44533.260472] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[44533.260488] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[44533.273177] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain 
[44533.273181] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[44533.273184] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[44533.273188] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[44533.273191] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[44533.273195] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[44533.273198] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[44533.273202] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[44534.078574] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[44539.626843] wlan0: authenticate with 94:0c:6d:c0:51:ca (try 1)
[44539.628827] wlan0: authenticated
[44539.629214] wlan0: associate with 94:0c:6d:c0:51:ca (try 1)
[44539.631514] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 94:0c:6d:c0:51:ca (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[44539.631522] wlan0: associated
[44539.633667] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[44551.104169] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[44987.241475] wlan0: deauthenticating from 94:0c:6d:c0:51:ca by local choice (reason=3)
[44987.288269] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[44987.288279] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[44987.288294] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[44987.309376] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain 
[44987.309383] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[44987.309385] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[44987.309389] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[44987.309393] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[44987.309396] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[44987.309400] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[44987.309403] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[44988.074180] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[44993.648439] wlan0: authenticate with 94:0c:6d:c0:51:ca (try 1)
[44993.651354] wlan0: authenticated
[44993.651651] wlan0: associate with 94:0c:6d:c0:51:ca (try 1)
[44993.653990] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 94:0c:6d:c0:51:ca (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[44993.653995] wlan0: associated
[44993.655984] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[45005.400035] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Got to say i'm sorry; at that time the code posted here http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11356188&postcount=35 seemd to have worked but haven't.

I found a solution on launchpad which seem to work - */etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945.conf*
`options iwl3945 disable_hw_scan=0`.
It works even after a system reboot. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From your log, it looks like the problem is here:

```
[44987.241475] wlan0: deauthenticating from 94:0c:6d:c0:51:ca by local choice (reason=3)
```

I recommend doing some research on 'deauthenticating by local choice reason=3', however the closest to your problem seems to be this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/548992

In the bug report, the root cause of the problem is a power management. Try running:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

This will permanently disable power management for your wireless adapter (it *should* be persisted between reboots) and prevent frequent connection drops.

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried that but got the following: `Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) : SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.`.

Comment: Apparently power management for this driver was disabled in newer kernels due to frequent connection drops. Kinda ironic. If you have administration access to the router on your network, you can try different settings - e.g. use 802.11g mode only and strictly WPA, or WPA2 for encryption (if you are on secured network).

Comment: Another recommendation is from Ubuntu Forums although it's a speed related problem - http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11356188&postcount=35 - anyway, if everything fails, WICD still seems to be solution.

Comment: I did seem to make the problem go away (or at least recurring less often) by adding `wireless-power off` at the end of `/etc/network/interfaces` and reboot. Now I'm putting the wireless interface under constant load for sometime to see if the problem is indeed fixed.

Comment: Nope. Still getting random disconnect every now and then. :( But the intervals do feels much further apart.

Comment: Well, if the problem is power management related you'd lose connection during inactivity - see if the connection drops if you let run ping to your gateway (router) indefinitely. Also I recommend to comment on [the bug report I've mentioned](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/548992), this is clearly a problem in NetworkManager, wpa_supplicant, or network stack.

Comment: Also, see this question - http://askubuntu.com/questions/69141/intel-3956abg-wpa-wireless-not-working-on-thinkpad-t60 - again, the solution is to use wicd which isn't as pretty as NM but apparently it just works...

Comment: From other question - you could try to change MTU settings as described on http://mylinuxramblings.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/how-to-stop-ubuntu-11-10-wireless-dropping-out/

Answer (score 0):

This has solved my problem! Yes finally!

I found a solution on launchpad which seems to have worked -

Open `/etc/modprobe.d/iwl3945.conf` file and set `iwl3945 disable_hw_scan=0`.

It works even after a system reboot. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

While these suggestions did help me, I was using a different Intel based wifi adapter and my solution to the problem did indeed seem to be rooted in the power management of the adapter. Here is where I found the answer to permanently turn off power management:

http://syntaxionist.rogerhub.com/intel-centrino-wireless-n-2200-ubuntu-1mbps-workaround.html

Although it seems like it would have worked, just calling:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

should have worked, it seemed that it didnt have an effect. Yet the link above did work after restarting the computer.

Old question, new answer for the sake of others looking for a solution while searching, this answer came up high on search results for a similar problem.