# After network restart, device not ready Xubuntu 16.04, Intel 3945ABG Wireless card

Tags: networking

When my WiFi drops, I disable and re-enable WiFi. Sometimes, this doesn't fix the problem. It will show no networks. I reset the network by `sudo service network-manager restart` and then I get `device not ready`

I end up having to reboot and it fixes things temporarily, until the next time. How do I fix this so that I don't have to restart the computer every now and again?

As suggested by @VBF below, I ran these commands and got these results when things stopped working.

Here is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
enp9s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:8b:dd:24:32  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10682 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10682 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:724653 (724.6 KB)  TX bytes:724653 (724.6 KB)
```

The output of `nmcli co`:

```
NAME                       UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE 
NETGEAR63                  7796f00a-6ffa-4154-aff1-62af90c3d8e8  802-11-wireless  --     
NETGEAR63 1                979c058f-cb41-4910-bbab-37b86d76bb5e  802-11-wireless  --     
Samsung Galaxy Avant 4539  b8601380-8e76-4c9c-be74-cfa7f33865be  802-11-wireless  --     
Wired connection 1         93b93cbb-b063-30aa-8ea4-7cc61db203f6  802-3-ethernet   --
```

The output of the command `nmcli networking connectivity check` was

```
none
```

And and lastly I tried both `nmcli con up id "NETGEAR63 1"` and `nmcli con up id "NETGEAR63"` and got this output:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
```

Update: My laptop uses an Intel 3945ABG wireless card.

Comment: Please give `ifconfig`, `nmcli co`, `nmcli networking connectivity check` output. Try `nmcli con up id NAME` where `NAME` is the connection in the `nmcli co` output

Comment: Do you mean while it is having problems, or whenever?

Comment: Yes, whenever you have an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking around on the internet, the problem may be related to power management for the WiFi card related to these pages:
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005875.html and [Wireless connection keeps dropping with an Intel 3945ABG card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73607/wireless-connection-keeps-dropping-with-an-intel-3945abg-card)

To solve the problem, power management for the card may have to be disabled. The above forum pages solutions doesn't work for the version of Ubuntu I have (16.04).

To turn of the power management of the wifi, do the following:

Run `iwconfig`. You will see your chip-set as well as whether power management is on or off.
Open `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`, you should see

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

Change the 3 to a 2, save and reboot.

Run `iwconfig` and you should hopefully see that `Power Management:off`

Source: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/internet

Comment: We should see if the new edit fixes the problem.

Comment: After a week, I still have no problems!

Comment: I have a intel wireless 7260ac card on a system 76 laptop and this worked for me.  My 5ghz kept disconnecting then my 2.4ghz kept disconnecting after I made this change the disconnects stopped happening.  Hopefully they fix this issue.  I'm running ubuntu 16.04.1